# Not getting a response on MDN AJAX example

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I previously attempted to interact with PHP using AJAX (1st time using Javascript to any significant degree) and had no success, so I tried to start with the basics using a Mozilla Developer Network example as a test:

Example - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

That isn't working either even though I copy-pasted it straight from the site with only one change (setting the url to my test page, running on XAMPP). When I click the button to run the MDN script, the resulting output is the alert "There was a problem with the request".

I'm using Firebug to check the result, and it shows a "200 OK" code for Status. If I understand the script correctly, shouldn't that not lead to an error message?

Here is the code from the example (along with the code from the Foundation framework I was using, in case that's somehow the issue):

```
    <!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
<span id="ajaxButton" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline">
  Make a request
</span>

<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var httpRequest;
  document.getElementById("ajaxButton").onclick = function() { makeRequest('http://localhost:8000/pages/test.html'); };

  function makeRequest(url) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
      httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
      try {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } 
      catch (e) {
        try {
          httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e) {}
      }
    }

    if (!httpRequest) {
      alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
      return false;
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
    httpRequest.open('GET', url);
    httpRequest.send();
  }

  function alertContents() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        alert(httpRequest.responseText);
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }
})();
</script>
</body>
```

And here is the code for the test HTML page that I made:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

Test


</body>
</html>
```

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT - Adding the original PHP script being referenced. I originally tried to use an altered version of the MDN script on this but likewise couldn't get it to work:

```
<?php
require ('includes/config.inc.php'); 
require (MYSQL);

$u = NULL;
$P = NULL;

$u = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, $_GET['username']);
$p = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, $_GET['password']);
$q = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE (username='$u' AND password=SHA1('$p')) AND active IS NULL";      
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

if (@mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) { // A match was made.

    $a = 'True';
    print json_encode($a);

} else { // No match was made.

    $a = 'False';
    print json_encode($a);
}

?>
```

2ND EDIT - Thanks for the suggestion about the console log, that did it. All I needed to do was enable CORS and now it works fine.

Comment: Can include `php` at original post ?

Comment: It wouldn't say there was a problem if the response code from the server were 200. Are you sure you're looking at the response code of the AJAX request and not of the main page? You should also be able to see the payload in Firebug (which should include the whole test page).

Comment: So what does the status say? `console.log(httpRequest.status)` ?

Comment: The console says: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/pages/test.html. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: Your original file must be opened from localhost then (see your browser URL).